# How do I access a function of a different object

Tags: javascript

I have the following code -

```
function test() {
        a = {
            name : 'John',
            greeting : 'Hello',
            sayIt : function() {
                return this.greeting + ', ' +
                    this.name + '!';
            }
        };

        b = {
            name : 'Jane',
            greeting : 'Hi'
        };
}
```

How can I access sayIt using b? Ofcourse b.sayIt will not work. I need to print 'Hi Jane'. How can I pass the name and greeting of b to sayIt function?

Comment: like a.sayIt()? or a["sayIt"]?

Comment: yes. but i need to do something like b.sayIt(). Is it possible to do a b.a.sayIt()?

Comment: Unless you want `a` and `b` to be global, you should `var` them.

Comment: `a.sayIt.call(b)`, but I highly doubt that is what you want. http://davidshariff.com/blog/javascript-inheritance-patterns/

Comment: Looks more like the `sayIt` function shouldn't be part of the object at all, but a regular function that takes arguments.

Comment: Can you explain why it is necessary to do this?

Comment: The code doesn't make a lot of sense from a structural point of view, but then again, the function name is 'test'. Most logical to me would be to make an object 'person', set the sayIt method on its prototype, and set the properties on instantiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply` or `call`.

```
a.sayIt.apply(b);
```

These change the value of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `a` and `b` from the function. Then you can do this:

```
function test() {
  var a = {
    name : 'John',
    greeting : 'Hello',
    sayIt : function() {
      return this.greeting + ', ' +
      this.name + '!';
    }
  };

  var b = {
    name : 'Jane',
    greeting : 'Hi'
  };

  return this;
}

test().a.sayIt.call(test().b); // Hi Jane!
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vJLNA/)

Answer (score 0):

You also could use

```
b = new a();
b.name = 'Jane',
b.greeting = 'Hi'
b.sayIt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
a.sayIt.apply(b)
```